# SQL Percentage of salesmen that meets conditions

Tags: sql, percentage

So I need a SQL query that calculates the percentage of salesmen(verkoper) that have an open order amount less then 600 euro.

I already made a sql query that gives me those numbers and for what I could see there were 4 out of 5 salesmen who had this. (So a percentage of 80%). Now I need to translate that query to a query that shows only that percentage, but I can't figure this out. Can someone help me with this solution?

The query that shows 5 salesmen with the total amount of open orders:

```
SELECT mw.mdwnr, SUM(br.aantal*ap.prijs)
FROM bestelling bs
JOIN bestelregel br
ON bs.bestelnr = br.bestelnr
JOIN artikelprijs ap
ON ap.artikelnr = br.artikelnr
JOIN medewerker mw
ON bs.verkoper = mw.mdwnr
WHERE bs.besteldatum between begindatum and einddatum
AND bs.betaaldatum is null
GROUP BY mw.mdwnr
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use your query as a subquery and do:

```
select avg(case when col2 < 600 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_orders_under_600
from (<your query here>) q;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I already thought I needed to use a subquery, but I couldn't get it to work.. I only need to change the ratio to percentage with FORMAT, but that is not so difficult.

Comment: @TimHellegers . . . You can get a value from 0 to 100 by using `100.0` instead of `1.0`.